# What is the code/bypass for a linebreak in Smallbasic? Or how to bypass error messages Smallbasic?

Tags: smallbasic

I am using MS Smallbasic and **not** the *online version*. In the *online version* you can just use **TextWindow.WriteLine()** but in the *downloaded version* you get an error message as it needs at least one argument and can't be empty.

I tried using a variable and an array with it but it still does not work.
Is there a *other way* to make a **linebreak**?

> Thank you if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Textwindow.WriteLine("")** as linebreak.

See Demo:

```
TextWindow.WriteLine("ASCII CODE TABLE")
TextWindow.WriteLine("")
TextWindow.WriteLine(" + 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F")
For code = 0 To 127
  rem = Math.Remainder(code, 16)
  div = Math.Floor(code / 16)
  If rem = 0 Then
    TextWindow.Write(Text.Append(div, "0 "))
  EndIf
  If (code < 7) Or ((10 < code) And (code <> 13)) Then
    TextWindow.Write(Text.GetCharacter(code) + " ")
  Else
    TextWindow.Write("  ")
  EndIf
  If rem = 15 Then
    TextWindow.WriteLine("")
  EndIf
EndFor
TextWindow.WriteLine("")
TextWindow.Write("07=BEL ")
TextWindow.Write("08=BS ")
TextWindow.Write("09=TAB ")
TextWindow.Write("0A=LF ")
TextWindow.WriteLine("0D=CR")
TextWindow.WriteLine("")
```